# Como gravar e exibir imagens usando PostgreSQL e Laravel 5.1

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, postgresql, imagem, laravel-5

Tenho o seguinte código no meu Controller para salvar a imagem no banco de dados, não da nenhum erro então acho que funciona certo.

```
$data = Input::file('assinatura');
$escaped = bin2hex($data);
$tecnico->assinatura = $escaped;
$tecnico->save();
```

Fica assim na minha tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que não sei como exibir essa imagem, se eu coloco:

```
<img src="{{ $tecnico->assinatura }}" />
```

Da esse erro:

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 469:
>
> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Comment: Raylan salvar imagens como strings (sendo que você usa hex e na verdade o mais eficiente seria base64) ou [blobs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOB) na database é uma ideia ruim, prefira sempre fazer upload da imagem para o servidor e guardar na database o caminho para onde ela está salva.

Comment: Imagino que o upload seja melhor @BrunoRB, mas como são poucas imagens e pequenas, achei que gravando direto ficaria mais facil. Caso realmente não consiga ou me mostrem que realmente não vale nada apena eu vou tentar fazendo upload em um diretório no servidor.